community wiki label on 'accurate data' question
I was hoping to find out how/why my question "what broker/feed/api setup allows for recording the most accurate data (cheaply)?" was labelled 'community wiki'?
Here's the link: What broker/feed/APIsetup allows for recording the most accurate data (cheaply)?
Looking at other stackexchange sites I found:

When should a question be Community Wiki?

...
If it is a poll. This reduces reputation harvesting and encourages
  people to vote freely for answers that
  are not their own.

No other questions should be set to
  this mode or users will be discouraged
  from answering.

also


If you're trying to make a list of
  resources, your question should be
  community wiki. You should also
  request that people post one
  resource per answer so that it is
  easy for people to sort the list by
  voting up/down.
If it would be
  inappropriate for you to accept an
  answer (i.e. you know when you're
  posting the question that there
  isn't really an answer), then your
  question should be community wiki.
If you'd like to post a
  shoot-from-the-hip answer that you'd
  like other people to flesh out, or
  if you'd like an answer that pulls
  together elements from many other
  answers to make something more
  complete, you should make a
  community wiki answer.


Based on these I don't think the question should have been made a community wiki. I can understand how it might look like my intention was list-making or polling, but it wasn't. My intention was to find the most accurate data setup, which I think I did (exception institutional setups).
Can someone explain?
EDIT:
@robert et al.
Sorry if that seemed like a statement. I was hoping to engage discussion. I agree with the criteria just not with it's application. Especially in light of many other questions which seem much more in the way of 'lists' but which are not labelled community wikis. See, e.g., this question and this one. Also, compare my question to this question, which is a similar topic but which instead asks for individual experiences.


What setups gives the most accurate data and depth?

The question is asking users to submit their suggestions and product recommendations based on their own experiences and preferences. It's not at all unusual to mark these "product recommendation" threads as community wiki. There is no canonical "right" answer to a question like this. The value is having the entire list to work from. 
That is the criteria I used in making it wiki.

I did not ask for suggestions nor for product recommendations. I asked a question of fact: which setup gives the most accurate data. For my question, there is absolutely a right answer and a wrong answer, based on how fine the granularity of the data is. Furthermore, the value of the question is not int he list, as your criteria seems to suggest. The value was in knowing what the setup inquired about is.

added to my question

can the cw status be changed now or not?

No, there is no way to reverse a community wiki setting. Sorry.

thanks for the response
